# MySQL .NET save/edit button not doing anything

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, crud

I am doing a simple edit of a table, And I seem to be stuck with getting it to update the values i change in the DB. It is not throwing any error at me to work with.

This is my button Code:

```
protected void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 saveOperator2();
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Single();
 if (Request.QueryString.HasKeys() && !IsPostBack)
  {
    operatorID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["Oid"]);
  }
}
private void saveOperator2()
{
 connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
 parser = new MySQLParser(connection);
 {
  connection.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE operator SET DPFreservingrawmaterials = @DPFreservingrawmaterials WHERE idOperator = @idOperator", connection);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@DPFreservingrawmaterials", DPFreservingrawmaterialsTextBox.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@idOperator", operatorID);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  cmd.Dispose();
 }
 connection.Close();
}
```

EDIT#32 -

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET operator DPFreservingrawmaterials = '1' WHERE idOperator = 10038' at line 1

Breaking at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Can you try adding your parameter with `cmd.Parameters.Add("@param", val);`? Also your idOperator needs to be added through the Pameters.Add method.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? If ExecuteNonQuery returns 0, it's probably because the where clause didn't find any matches.

Comment: Have you got any errors?

Comment: @Webbanditten Trying your suggestion.

Comment: Your missing `'`, Please update your code so we can see your edits.

Comment: @Webbanditten New to using stackoverflow, my apologies. I did a edit on my first post.

Comment: Prøv  `MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE operator DPFreservingrawmaterials = @DPFreservingrawmaterials WHERE idOperator = @idOperator", connection);`

Comment: Did another edit to the main post. Basicly getting the "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Comment: Forgot "SET" in SQL command

Comment: @Webbanditten - Did another small edit of the error code after adding SET.

Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Is it returning errors?

Comment: @Webbanditten Updated the error in the main post.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET operator DPFreservingrawmaterials = '1' WHERE idOperator = 10038' at line 1

Breaking at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: "SET" is missing in the command that you have specified.

Comment: `SET operator DPFreservingrawmaterials = @DPFreservingrawmaterials` isn't valid *SQL* syntax. Create a *proper* SQL Statement first, then try to use ADO.NET to call it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not completely sure what you mean. Why is it not valid?

Comment: The syntax is `SET field = value` not `Set operator field =  value`. That's what the error message says.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ah i see. I miss placed the SET after forgetting to ADD it in here. Still getting the error tho.

Answer (score 0):

What is the correct field `operatorID` or `idOperator`?

```
UPDATE operator `SET operatorID` = @idOperator, DPFreservingrawmaterials = @DPFreservingrawmaterials WHERE `idOperator` = "+ operatorID, connection
```

"`SET operatorID`" then in Where clause `WHERE idOperator`

Comment: idOperator is the ID I am getting from the DB